# right way to use title attribute with svg sprite

Tags: html, svg, title, css-sprites

I want to have a 'mouseover title', like the `title="text text"`in HTML does it, but want to use it with an SVG sprite. This is what i tried:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 8 8" id="random-svg" class="svg-controls">
  <title>start random mode</title>
  <use xlink:href="/bower_components/open-iconic/sprite/open-iconic.svg#random">
  </use>
</svg>
```

The description does not always appear. Sometimes it appears - sometimes not . Is there a position defined where the `<title>` should be placed ideally?

Comment: You'll need some JavaScript I'm afraid. Tutorial + code: http://www.mecxpert.de/svg/tooltips.html

Comment: Can you provide a working example that shows it not working? It works for me.

Comment: This is an interting gist on the subject: https://gist.github.com/davidhund/564331193e1085208d7e